# Override frontcontroller or modulefrontcontroller init() method for checkout

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

My problem is as follows. I have created a payment module for prestashop 1.7. The order is validated // created when the payment is initiated. This happens in the payment.php controller by using the validateOrder Method:

```
        $this->module->validateOrder(
                (int) $cartId,
                $this->module->statuses[$orderStatus],
                $prestaTotal,
                'paymentmodule',
                null,
                array(),
                null,
                false,
                $customer->secure_key
                );
```

So a new order is created and the cart is now related to an order. And the customer get's redirected to the payment provider. They can eigther pay, or press the "cancel" button.

The webhook.php recieves the status of the order from the payment provider and updates the order status in prestashop. If the order is paid, they get redirected to the order confirmation page. But if it's cancelled, the cart is gone.

This happens, because prestashop checks if the order exists. And if it does, the cart gets deleted. The init() method in FronController.php is responsible for this:

```
/* Cart already exists */
    if ((int) $this->context->cookie->id_cart) {
        if (!isset($cart)) {
            $cart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);
        }

        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($cart) && $cart->OrderExists()) {
            PrestaShopLogger::addLog('Frontcontroller::init - Cart cannot be loaded or an order has already been placed using this cart', 1, null, 'Cart', (int) $this->context->cookie->id_cart, true);
            unset($this->context->cookie->id_cart, $cart, $this->context->cookie->checkedTOS);
            $this->context->cookie->check_cgv = false;
        }
```

So i created a Method in return.php controller to make a copy of the cart which belongs to an existing order, so you have a new cart:

```
class PaymentModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $cartId = Tools::getValue('cart_id');
        $cart = new Cart((int) $cartId);
        $data['info'] = $this->module->getPaymentBy('cart_id', (int)$cartId);
                $orderId = Order::getOrderByCartId($cartId);
                $orderStatus = $data['info']['bank_status'];

                if (Validate::isLoadedObject($cart) && 
                $cart->OrderExists() && 
                $orderStatus === 'cancelled')
                {
                    $oldCart = new Cart(Order::getCartIdStatic($orderId, $this->context->customer->id));
                    $duplication = $oldCart->duplicate();
                    if (!$duplication || !Validate::isLoadedObject($duplication['cart'])) 
                    {
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Sorry. We cannot renew your order.');
                    } 
                    elseif (!$duplication['success']) 
                    {
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Some items are no longer available, and we are unable to renew your order.');
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->context->cookie->id_cart = $duplication['cart']->id;
                        $context = $this->context;
                        $context->cart = $duplication['cart'];
                        CartRule::autoAddToCart($context);
                        $this->context->cookie->write();
                        if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1) 
                        {
                            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc');
                        }
                    Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');
                    }   

                }
      }
```

A copy of the cart will be created they get redirected to the checkout.

So hooray, there cart is not gone (which normally happens if the order exists for the cart), they can choose a different payment option and a brand new order is created.

But, a customer can also press the "back to previous page" button of the browser when they are on the payment providers page.

[image]

They would be redirected back to the checkout, but in this case, my Method isn't called so the cart is gone. This happens because the init() Method in Frontcontroller.php is called. And because the order is validated // created, the cart gets deleted.

So, i added a new controller in the payment module named checkout:

```
$this->controllers = array('payment, return, webhook, checkout');
```

and placed checkout.php in the folder controllers/front of my module.

I extended the class FrontController and created an override for the init() Method. My code:

```
class PaymentModuleFrontController extends FrontController
{

    public function init()
    {

        $data = array();
        $cartId = $this->context->cart->id;
        $cart = new Cart($cartId);
        $orderId = Order::getOrderByCartId($cartId);
        $data['info'] = $this->module->getPaymentBy('cart_id', (int)$cartId); //gets payment from db. I checked it and this is correct
        $orderStatus = $data['info']['status']; //gets the status. I checked it and it's correct

        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($cart) && 
        $cart->OrderExists() && 
        $orderStatus === 'open') 
        {
            $oldCart = new Cart(Order::getCartIdStatic($orderId, $this->context->customer->id));
            $duplication = $oldCart->duplicate();
            if (!$duplication || !Validate::isLoadedObject($duplication['cart'])) 
            {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Problem duplicating cart.');
            } 
            elseif (!$duplication['success']) 
            {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Problem duplicating cart.');
            } 
            else 
            {
                $this->context->cookie->id_cart = $duplication['cart']->id;
                $context = $this->context;
                $context->cart = $duplication['cart'];
                CartRule::autoAddToCart($context);
                $this->context->cookie->write();
                if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1) 
                {
                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc');
              }
              Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');
            }
        }
        parent::init();

    }


}
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong because this works fine for my return controller but it still removes the cart if i go back to the previous page with the browser button.

Could i use my code in a hook which is used on the checkout / order page and add it in my PaymentModule Class ?

important, i want to establish this without creating an override file for FrontController.php so it has to be done with a module controller or by my payment module Class.

I hope someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160726/discussion-between-sub-hdr-and-aurora).

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to validate an order even before the customer completes checkout? Because even if you get this working what's stopping me from just going to your store and just doing "click your payment, go back, click your payment, go back..." and your store will end up with tons of useless orders, also it might be annoying for customers to receive confirmation emails before they even complete checkout?

Comment: Hi @TheDrot yes there is. I want to send the order id to the payment provider. In the old situation, i validated the order in the webhook, but i can't make second request to update the payment information. As you know, if the order isn't validated before it redirects to the payment provider, i can only send the cart id as reference which is annoying. They do recieve a confirmation email, but, if the order is cancelled or expired, they also recieve an email that it's been cancelled.

Comment: @TheDrot about the "Because even if you get this working what's stopping me from just going to your store and just doing "click your payment, go back, click your payment, go back..." and your store will end up with tons of useless orders" I can add a function to delete the cancelled order after a copy of the cart is made to prevent this from happening. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I don't know much about pretashop, so this might be a stupid question, but can't you just pass the cart ID to the payment provider as an order ID and create the order from the cart ID after successful payment?

Comment: @masterfloda Thank you for taking the time to help. The cart id is different from the order id. In prestashop (on the admin orders page) the cart id is not specified // showing so this makes it hard for shopowners to find the right payment with the right order. I can't change the order id to be the same as the cart id. When an order is created, it does use the cart id but in the end, the order number differs.

Comment: OK, that makes total sense. But still, your approach feels a bit hacky. I googled a bit and came across this: https://payzen.io/es-ES/free-payment-plugins/prestashop/managing-the-prestashop-order-id.html

Comment: Hi @masterfloda thank you for your efford. As i described, in the old situation i did the same. After the payment is complete (like Payzen does), i would have the order validated // created. In the new situation i want to validate it before finalizing the payment. It might feel hacky but in my opinion it's not (I am going "a bit against the flow" though).  Like TheDrot said, about going back and forth, if i willingly wanted to harm a shopowner, i could do the same with the standard bankpayment module to create a lot of orders.

Answer (score 1):

The approach that you are following to create an order is not correct. Instead of creating the order when the user is redirected to the Payment provider, you should create the order on the basis of the response received from the Payment Provider.

This means that the order is generated only if the payment is successful, else the user will see the error on the checkout page and the cart will stay as it is as well.

The approach that you are following is very risky as you are overriding a method that is called on each and every page in PrestaShop and my recommendation is that you should not be doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set id_cart in your payment url and get it in your controller. So when you create a payment option set id_cart in url query:

```
public function hookDisplayPayment($params){
    $externalOption = new PaymentOption();
    $externalOption->setCallToActionText('Payment Method')
          ->setAction($this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'payment', ['id_cart'=>$this->context->cart->id], true))
          ->setAdditionalInformation($plugin->description)
          ->setLogo(Media::getMediaPath(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/logo.jpg'));
    return $externalOption;
}
```

Then get related cart in payment controller:

```
class PaymentModuleFrontController extends FrontController
{

    public function init()
    {
        $cart = new Cart(Tools::getValue('id_cart'));
        //more...
    }
 }
```